# AWS Cloudfront: Am I "streaming" video or am I "downloading" video?

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, flv, amazon-cloudfront

Have a flash video player that mimics the functionality of the youtube player regarding video input. I believe this is called "progressive download". I'm using Amazon Cloudfront to server up the video, and it asks me if the distribution is "download" or "streaming". Which one should I choose for this kind of player?

note: this is NOT live video streaming...its just basic, static FLV file playing similar to what the youtube player does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be streaming as someone would play the video. Download is downloading the .flv file and then playing it on a person's computer rather than in his web browser.

Answer (score 5):

When the distribution is **download** requests will be served via normal HTTP (video players call this progressive download).

CloudFront also runs Adobe Flash Media Server -- these servers are the **streaming** distribution option. You can read more RTMP support in the [developer guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RTMPStreaming.html).